# Get All Permutations of Non-Conflicting Event Schedules

Tags: algorithm, big-o, time-complexity

I am attempting to create a set of class schedules from a list of available classes and I want to be able to find the set of all possible (and valid) schedules that could be made from the list of available courses.

I am aware of the Activity Selection Problem/Event Scheduling Problem seen [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithms/Greedy_Algorithms) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activity_selection_problem) but I do not know how to modify these algorithms to give me a complete set of schedules rather than just *a* complete schedule.

More succintly, how can the activity selection problem be modified to give a set of all possible non-conflicting event schedules?

---

I should also note that I believe that a solution to this would probably be in O(n^n) time, so if anyone has a suggestion for a solution to a complete scheduling problem that has a lower asymptotic running time, please share thoughts.

I am aware of the fact that this approach is a variant of recursive backtracking with some modification, but I can't seem to find anything in literature about it.

Answer (score 3):

I would try ordering all of your activities based on start time. Take the first one, and suppose that it's in the schedule. Then proceed through the list and construct a schedule from the remaining classes that start after the first one ends. Once you've constructed all of these, repeat, but exclude the first class from your schedule. Your algorithm will just be recursively seeing what schedules result from the inclusion or exclusion of a class. Your runtime will be O(2^n) though (I don't think you can do it in O(n*2), but I could be wrong). I assume the specialized algorithms (for finding the best possible schedule) exist because the runtime for finding all possible schedules is so bad.

Comment: So then to construct the set of schedules, once a schedule is completed from starting with a class, I would add that schedule to the set and keep recursing? And at the top level of the recursion (that is, when selecting a class to start with), I would just iterate over all classes?

Comment: Your recursive function will take some parameters: a set of classes, and an earliest time. The first call will have your set of all classes and the earliest time will be NULL. From within, you'll have two cases: You add the first available class, or you don't. In each case, your set of classes is modified to remove the first available class (and any classes that start before the current earliest time). In the case where you include the class, your earliest time is set to that class's end time. In the other case, your earliest time is unchanged. You've found a schedule when you add no class.